# Is there some sync functionality in normal libraries like in the mysite onedrive?

Tags: onedrive-for-business

I am using SP 2013 onpremise. When I go to the mysite onedrive I see a library. In top right corner I see a sync button where I can sync the library to my offline desktop. When I go to some normal document library in some intranet site collection I do not see this sync button. Is there some way to save the documents of my library offline to my desktop?

See [this printscreen](http://s23.postimg.org/e33evem8a/mysite_onedrive.jpg) for the onedrive library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Normal" document libraries can be synced so you have an offline copy of documents. If you don't see the Sync button in SP 2013 on premise you might have sync disabled for that particular document library or across the site.

Check if sync is disabled for your document library:
Document library settings > Advanced settings > Offline client availability

Check if sync is disabled across your site:
Site settings > Search and offline availability > Offline Client Availability

By the way, you can also synchronise your document library with Outlook:
Document library > Ribbon > Library > Connect to Outlook